# sites.php confusion

Tags: multi-sites

My question is on the last line.

My local, development setup, each install separately managed with GIT:

---

MAMP Document Root is at: /Users/me/Sites/
I have several Drupal installs there, so:

```
/Users/me/Sites/D7InstallOne/sites/site1
/Users/me/Sites/D7InstallOne/sites/site2
/Users/me/Sites/D7InstallTwo/sites/site3
/Users/me/Sites/D7InstallTwo/sites/site4
/Users/me/Sites/D7InstallThree/sites/site5
/Users/me/Sites/D7InstallThree/sites/site6
```

I don't use the default site for any install, like at /Users/me/Sites/D7InstallOne/sites/default

---

vhosts files:

```
/Users/me/vhosts/site1.conf
/Users/me/vhosts/site2.conf
/Users/me/vhosts/site3.conf
/Users/me/vhosts/site4.conf
/Users/me/vhosts/site5.conf
/Users/me/vhosts/site6.conf
```

Format of each of the .conf files (/Users/me/vhosts/site1.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /Users/me/Sites/D7InstallOne
  ServerName site1
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Contents of /etc/hosts:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       site1
127.0.0.1       site2
127.0.0.1       site3
127.0.0.1       site4
127.0.0.1       site5
127.0.0.1       site6

55.255.255.255  broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

---

In /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf, I have the following two lines:

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

In /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf, I have the following lines:

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

---

For local development there are two sections in sites.php with sample code.

First example section:

```
 $sites = array(
   'key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2',
 );
```

Second example section:

```
 URL: http://what_do_I_put_here?
 $sites[' key1'] = 'value1';
 $sites['key2'] = 'value2';
```

I have tried every permutation I can sanely think of and have had no success. The instructions for this file and discussions on the web do not take into consideration the possibility of my setup, which, yes, I am in love with.

Do I need both or just one of the above sections? If just one, which? What is the correct syntax for the above sites.php setup? At what url do I then find site1?